# Can I change global variables value when users close window

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

```
public class Global : System.Web.HttpApplication
    {
        public static int timeStamp = 0;
        protected void Application_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)        
        {
        }
        protected void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Session_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
        protected void Application_End(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
        }
    }
```

My ASP.NET(c#) page has Global variable in `Global.asax` class. When users close the window, I want to set that Global variable by 1.

Comment: Beside the fact that global variables do not exist in .NET/C#, your `timeStamp` is shared by _all users_ of your web site. Pretty sure, this is not intended.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can't set the global variable when then user closes the window.
you can set it,but if the user again opens the window it automatically have the old value(value in the initialization)

Comment: But if he check cookies for session data on that ip an machine the user can get back to its previous session